# Delete a bond interface created from /etc/network/interfaces (ifupdown)?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, bonding

I made an attempt bonding two interfaces into one, created `bond0`, and found it unsatisfactory. I then reverted all changes made to `/etc/network/interfaces` and ran `systemctl restart networking.service`, but the bond interface still existed (shows up in `ifconfig` and `ip link` commands) and I had to run `ip link set bond0 down` or `ifconfig bond0 down` to force kick it out. How do I completely remove this interface without rebooting the server?

I'm on Debian Buster. The file was originally like this:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    # regular network settings like address, netmask, gateway etc.
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
    # regular network settings like address, netmask, gateway etc.
```

I turned both interfaces into one bond by changing it into this:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    # regular network settings like address, netmask, gateway etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modern command to manage bond interfaces is, like for most other interfaces, [`ip link`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-link.8), here [along with *sysfs*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt?h=v4.19#n1396) for the possible few things not handled directly through [(rt)netlink](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/rtnetlink.7#DESCRIPTION). In [this case](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-link.8#ip_link_delete_-_delete_virtual_link):

```
ip link delete dev bond0
```

Any interface still enslaved when removing the bond will be detached, so there's no need to detach it first (using `ip link set DEVICE nomaster`).

An [alternate *sysfs* method](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt?h=v4.19#n1421) to do the same is:

```
echo -bond0 > /sys/class/net/bonding_masters
```

Comment: Ah, yes. This `iproute2` is what I'm using from day to day.

Answer (score 2):

bonding interfaces are managed by `ifenslave(8)` command line utility.

Below is an extract of the manpage:

```
NAME
     ifenslave -- Attach and detach slave network devices to a bonding device.

SYNOPSIS
     ifenslave [-acdfhuvV] [--all-interfaces] [--change-active] [--detach] [--force] [--help] [--usage] [--verbose] [--version] master slave ...

DESCRIPTION
     ifenslave is a tool to attach and detach slave network devices to a bonding device.  A bonding device will act like a normal Ethernet network device to the kernel,
     but will send out the packets via the slave devices using a simple round-robin scheduler.  This allows for simple load-balancing, identical to "channel bonding" or
     "trunking" techniques used in switches.

     The kernel must have support for bonding devices for ifenslave to be useful.

OPTIONS
     -a, --all-interfaces
             Show information about all interfaces.

     -c, --change-active
             Change active slave.

     -d, --detach
             Removes slave interfaces from the bonding device.
```

**DISCLAIMER: i didn't tested the following**

To totally remove `bond0`, i would:

- `ifconfig bond0 down`
- `ifenslave -d bond0 eno1`
- `ifenslave -d bond0 eno2`
- ̀ rmmod bonding`

It should be enought.